# Can NUnit tests be cleaned up after they've been manually stopped?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, integration-testing

I am writing some tests for my application using NUnit and **Resharper as the test runner**. I have a test that creates entries in SQL using a custom data access layer and then checks to see if they were in fact, created. This check is done using a more direct connection using SqlDataAdapter.

After gathering the test results, the test entries are deleted from the table (within the test method, not in TearDown()). I've noticed that I often stop the tests in the middle because of various reasons and they obviously don't get cleaned up because I told the test to stop and so it never reaches the cleanup code. In my experience, even TearDown() doesn't get called when the tests are stopped using the stop button.

My question is: **When I hit the stop button, is there any way to invoke a cleanup procedure to remove tests artifacts?**

Comment: I doubt that is possible since you're essentially exiting the program. One note: that's integration testing, not unit-testing. The best course of action would be to let each test create its own database instead of having them mingle.

Comment: You're correct as to the part about integration testing. I feel that to ensure the reliabilty of the application, it's best to test in as close to real-life conditions as possible, and that's why I decided to test against the actual database. Is there an advantage to the tests creating their own databases? And is that a reliable way to test the entire chain from your app to the database schema?

EDIT: I accidentally pressed Enter before my comment was complete.

Comment: This is why mocking frameworks, such as NSubstitute, exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you stop the code execution you are stoping the procedure too so nothing else will be executed.

Something you can do is deleting on [`Set Up`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=setup&r=2.2.10). This method is executed before each test. This seems to be the best way to be sure that database is clean.

> **SetUpAttribute (NUnit 2.0)**
>
> This attribute is used inside a TestFixture to provide a common set of functions that are performed just before each test method is called. A TestFixture can have only one SetUp method. If more than one is defined the TestFixture will compile successfully, but its tests will not run.

**Sample**

```
namespace NUnit.Tests
{
  using System;
  using NUnit.Framework;

  [TestFixture]
  public class SuccessTests
  {
    [SetUp] public void Init()
    { /* ... */ }

    [TearDown] public void Dispose()
    { /* ... */ }

    [Test] public void Add()
    { /* ... */ }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a good idea, although the only caveat is that the last test will still leave some artifacts. I am thinking of just creating my own test runner in which tests can be cancelled using the CancellationToken and then some routines be run to clean them up. Although I'm not sure how monumental of a task I'm looking at.

Comment: @Anshul: last test will still have some artifacts but next test to run will delete them so no one will see others data :)

Comment: What about in between the last and the first run? I'd still see the data in that period right?

Comment: @Anshul: that's correct but if the database is only used for testing purposes seems irrelevant from my point of view.

Comment: Ideally before starting my application, all the tests would pass and that way all tests will cleanup properly. But I am thinking of a scenario where I accidentally run the tests and leave the app running. I have not quite decided if I should be running tests on a live database as I've made my app so that it will ignore test entries, but I don't want these entries to linger and build up over time. I have also thought about just having a replicated database on which I run the tests.

Comment: @Anshul: database should be only for testing purposes, don't think you should share it with other activities. You could even use sqlite if your architecture and schema allow it.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I was not thinking about the problem from an architecture point of view.

Answer (score 0):

If your test makes connection to DB, they are not really a "unit" test but more of integration test. Execution of unit test should not impact any other layer in the application.

I would suggest you to use "Dependency Injection" mechanism. In short, structure your custom data access layer such that while initializing it you pass SQL connection object to it. From your application, you pass on the actual connection but from your unit test you pass a mock connection. You can then assert mock connection on if a query or non-query was executed or not.

This way no data gets inserted at all in your DB and  you don't need to worry about cleaning it if your test is stopped in middle of execution.

You can look at an example of mocking SQL connection in this post: [Mocking data access Layer Rhino mock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024506/mocking-data-access-layer-rhino-mock)